# ClassNotFoundException when i add "provided" scope to the dependent project

Tags: scala, macros, sbt, classnotfoundexception

I have multiple project build in SBT, root project and project with macros and there is a `dependsOn(macros % "provided")` property on the root project. All tests are good, but when i try to run the root project locally or deploy it the remote server it fails with `ClassNotFoundException` saying that my `Macros$` file wasn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, `provided` means that you should provide the dependency manually, e.g. by adding a JAR file to the classpath. This is the same mechanism as Maven uses. So probably the dependency is somehow present on your workstation but not on the production server.

Comment: Thanks, there was a problem with publishTo task